# Populate a flat array with a dynamic number of values from each row of a result set

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-livewire, flatten

I have 2 tables one is category that has subcategories and I want to fetch the records and put in a single array. I have implemented this code:

```
public function searchItem(){
    $categories = ServiceCategory::with('subCategories')->get();

    $categoryArray = [];

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $categoryArray[] = [
            $category->category, 
            $category->subCategories->pluck('subcategory')->toArray(),
        ];
    }
    return $categoryArray;
}
```

The results I get is:

```
[["plumbing",["fitting","joints","pipe setting","wall setters","roof setters","drainage","walls and interior"]]
```

but what I want is something like this:

```
["plumbing","fitting","joints","pipe setting","wall setters","roof setters","drainage","walls and interior"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample output seems to indicate that you are only getting one row of results from `$categories`, so I am not sure that you actually need that `foreach()` loop.

The only time I ever use `array_push()` is when it is necessary to push multiple items into an array.  I find it very appropriate for this case to produce a flat result array.

```
public function searchItem(){
    $categoryArray = [];
    foreach (ServiceCategory::with('subCategories')->get() as $category) {
        array_push(
            $categoryArray,
            $category->category, 
            ...$category->subCategories->pluck('subcategory')->toArray()
        );
    }
    return $categoryArray;
}
```

Using this technique, the returned array will be a flat array thanks to the spread operator (`...`) before the plucked `subCategories` array.

Comment: great it is working as expected, I had no idea that we have the spread operator

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_merge(https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function of PHP.
This will help you to merge elements of 2 arrays.

```
public function searchItem(){
    $categories = ServiceCategory::with('subCategories')->get();

    $categoryArray = [];

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $categoryArray = array_merge($categoryArray, 
            array_merge(
                [$category->category],
                $category->subCategories->pluck('subcategory')->toArray()
            )
        );
    }
    return $categoryArray;
}
```

We need to add `$category->category` as an array as from your given output it seems that its a string.

Comment: It is not necessary to make iterated, nested `array_merge()` calls.  See my cleaner approach with `array_push()`.